# Chrome Extension : Gmail navigation

Tags: email, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension for Gmail. My extension shows the data from my website beside the Email body.

Its working fine if I go to a particular email directly or refresh the page.

But say if I move from inbox to a email or from one email to another, then my content scripts are not running.

I am not sure what could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail doesn't reload the page when you move from inbox to an email, it dynamically changes DOM. You should use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to handle it.

```js
// The following code handles new inserted nodes.
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.addedNodes);
    });    
});

observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true, subtree: true}); 
// call observer.disconnect(); if you don't need observer anymore
```

Comment: Mutation events are deprecated. Please rework your sample to use Observers.

Comment: @XAn They are, but you have to use Mutation events if you want to support older browsers.

Comment: Question is about Chrome Extensions.